# Embedding the Mészáros subdivision algebra in an Orlik-Terao localization

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-combinatorics, localization, yang-baxter-equations

The following is an open question (Question 4.1) from my paper *$t$-Unique
Reductions for Mészáros's Subdivision Algebra* ([published version in
SIGMA 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00839), and [slightly updated preprint
version with more references](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/subdiv-v7.pdf)). The subject is surprisingly rich and
well-connected, so I would expect answers to come from anywhere. Part of the
reason why I am posting this here is to learn more about some of these
connections, more so than just to get a specific question answered.

## 1. The subdivision algebra

Let $\mathbb{N}=\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $.

Let $\left[  m\right]  $ be the set $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,m\right\}  $ for each
$m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a commutative ring. Let $\beta\in\mathbf{k}$ and
$\alpha\in\mathbf{k}$. (The setup is interesting even in the case when
$\beta=0$ and $\alpha=0$.)

Fix a positive integer $n$. Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the polynomial ring
\begin{align}
\mathbf{k}\left[  x_{i,j}\ \mid\ \left(  i,j\right)  \in\left[  n\right]
^{2}\text{ satisfying }i<j\right]  .
\end{align}
This is a polynomial ring in $n\left(  n-1\right)  /2$ indeterminates
$x_{i,j}$ over $\mathbf{k}$.

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the ideal of $\mathcal{X}$ generated by all elements of
the form
\begin{align}
x_{i,j}x_{j,k}-x_{i,k}\left(  x_{i,j}+x_{j,k}+\beta\right)  -\alpha
\end{align}
for $\left(  i,j,k\right)  \in\left[  n\right]  ^{3}$ satisfying $i<j<k$.

For each $f\in\mathcal{X}$, we will let $\overline{f}$ denote the projection
of $f$ onto the quotient $\mathbf{k}$-algebra $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$.

**[If you are only looking for the question, scroll down to Section 2.]**

The ideal $\mathcal{J}$ and the quotient algebra $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$
(known as the "$n$-th type-A subdivision algebra") have a long history. For
$\alpha=0$, they originate in [a 2009 paper by Karola
Mészáros](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2011-363-08/S0002-9947-2011-05265-7/),
but variants (noncommutative, skew-commutative, partly commutative,
square-zero) appear all over the literature (I give a list of related algebras
at the end of Section 4.3 of my paper). These variants include

- the localization of a polynomial ring $\mathbf{k}\left[  s_{1},s_{2}
  ,\ldots,s_{n}\right]  $ at the multiplicative subset generated by the
  differences $s_{i}-s_{j}$ for all $i<j$ (see below);
- the cohomology of the complement of the braid arrangement (probably the
  oldest appearance, in [Arnold 1971](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01098313));
- the algebra of Heaviside functions of the halfspaces of this arrangement
  ([Gelfand/Varchenko 1987](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01077800));
- Kirillov's "quasi-classical Yang-Baxter algebra" ([Kirillov 1997](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9705003v3));
- a recent deformation of the Orlik-Terao algebra of the braid arrangement
  ([McBreen/Proudfoot 2015](http://content.algebraicgeometry.nl/2015-5/2015-5-026.pdf))

and probably more. There is also a [mysterious similarity to the defining
axiom of a Rota-Baxter algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286510/)
and a "hidden" $S_{n}$-action (which can be revealed by setting $x_{i,j}
=-\beta-x_{j,i}$ for all $\left(  i,j\right)  \in\left[  n\right]  ^{2}$
satisfying $i>j$, so that now $x_{i,j}$ is defined for any two distinct
elements $i$ and $j$ of $\left[  n\right]  $; this allows the symmetric group
$S_{n}$ to act by $\sigma x_{i,j}=x_{\sigma\left(  i\right)  ,\sigma\left(
j\right)  }$).

One of the results in my paper (Proposition 3.4) says the following:

> **Theorem 1.** The $\mathbf{k}$-module $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$ is free, and
>   has a basis consisting of the projections (onto $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$) of
>   all forkless monomials. Here, a *monomial* is always understood to be a formal
>   monomial in the $x_{i,j}$ (with no coefficients attached); and such a monomial
>   $\mathfrak{m}$ is called *forkless* if there exists no $\left(  i,j,k\right)
> \in\left[  n\right]  ^{3}$ with $i<j<k$ such that both $x_{i,j}$ and $x_{i,k}$
>   appear in $\mathfrak{m}$.

For example, the monomial $x_{1,3}x_{2,5}^{6}x_{3,4}$ is forkless, while the
monomial $x_{1,3}x_{2,4}x_{2,5}$ is not (since $x_{2,4}x_{2,5}$ is a "fork").

Theorem 1, like many PBW-like theorems, has an easy and a hard part. The easy
part is proving that the projections of the forkless monomials span
$\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$. The hard part is proving that they are $\mathbf{k}
$-linearly independent. Arguably, it is not really hard, since a Gröbner
basis does the whole work, but it still is an argument that makes me look for
an alternative.

## 2. The localization

One of the reasons for looking at $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$ is its similarity
to a very natural ring: the localization of a polynomial ring at the pairwise
differences of its indeterminates (or, equivalently, at its Vandermonde determinant).

Let $P=\mathbf{k}\left[  s_{1},s_{2},\ldots,s_{n}\right]  $ be the polynomial
ring in $n$ indeterminates $s_{1},s_{2},\ldots,s_{n}$ over $\mathbf{k}$. Let
$L$ be the localization of $P$ at the multiplicative subset $\left\{
s_{i}-s_{j}\ \mid\ \left(  i,j\right)  \in\left[  n\right]  ^{2}\text{
satisfying }i<j\right\}  $.

**[If you are only looking for the question, scroll down to Section 3.]**

The following fact, which I surprisingly could not
find anywhere in the literature, describes $L$ as a $\mathbf{k}$-module:

> **Theorem 2.** Consider the family of all elements of the form $\prod
> _{i=1}^{n}g_{i}\in L$, where each $g_{i}$ has either the form $\dfrac
> {1}{\left(  s_{i}-s_{j}\right)  ^{m}}$ for some $j\in\left\{  i+1,i+2,\ldots
> ,n\right\}  $ and $m>0$ or the form $s_{i}^{k}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
>   This family is a basis of the $\mathbf{k}$-module $L$.

This is proven by an iterated partial-fractial decomposition (which appears to
have a historical precedent -- the "method of Elliott" in MacMahon's partition
analysis), inducting on $n$.

The basis in Theorem 2 is similar to the "forkless monomials" basis in Theorem
1, if we forget for a moment about the possibility of the $g_{i}$ being
$s_{i}^{k}$. Indeed, if the $g_{i}$ are always of the form $\dfrac{1}{\left(
s_{i}-s_{j}\right)  ^{m}}$, then the resulting product $\prod_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}$
is a "forkless monomial" in the variables $\dfrac{1}{s_{i}-s_{j}}$. Does this
mean that $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$ embeds into $L$ as a $\mathbf{k}$-algebra?

At least in a particular case, it does:

> **Proposition 3.** Assume that $\beta=0$ and $\alpha=0$. Then, there is a
>   $\mathbf{k}$-algebra homomorphism $H:\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}\rightarrow L$
>   sending each $\overline{x_{i,j}}$ (with $i<j$) to $\dfrac{1}{s_{i}-s_{j}}$.
>   This homomorphism $H$ is injective (and, in fact, sends the "forkless
>   monomial" basis from Theorem 1 to a subfamily of the basis from Theorem 2).

The image of $H$ is the algebra $\mathbf{K}\left[  \alpha_{\mathcal{A}}
^{-1}\right]  $ in Definition 1.1 of [Orlik/Terao
1994](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118779934). That said, for some
reason, everyone in the hyperplane arrangement community seems to care mostly
about a finite-dimensional quotient of this algebra.

But back in the general case ($\beta$ and $\alpha$ arbitrary), the
homomorphism $H$ from Proposition 3 does not seem to generalize. Instead,
there is a more complicated homomorphism, which we will now construct.

## 3. The injectivity question

We define a $\mathbf{k}
$-algebra homomorphism $A:\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}\rightarrow L$ by
\begin{align}
A\left(  \overline{x_{i,j}}\right)  =\dfrac{s_{i}s_{j}+\beta s_{j}+\alpha
}{s_{i}-s_{j}}\qquad\text{for all }\left(  i,j\right)  \in\left[  n\right]
^{2}\text{ satisfying }i<j.
\end{align}
This $A$ is well-defined (easy to check). (My notations $s_{i}$ and $A$ here
correspond to the notations $\widetilde{q}_{i}$ and $\widetilde{A}$ from my paper.)

> **Question 1.** Is $A$ injective in the general case?

Note that I cannot answer this even in the case when $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=0$,
since $A$ (unlike $H$) does not send forkless monomials to elements of the
basis from Theorem 2.

To me, the nicest way to answer Question 1 (positively, of course) would be by
proving that $A$ sends forkless monomials to $\mathbf{k}$-linearly independent
elements of $L$. This would then yield that the forkless monomials are
themselves $\mathbf{k}$-linearly independent, thus reproving the hard part of
Theorem 1. Another option seems to be by extending the $\mathbf{k}$-algebra
$\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$ somehow and showing that $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{J}$
embeds into the new algebra, then finding an isomorphism from that algebra to
$L$.

Quite possibly, it is easier to work in a ring of Laurent series than to work
in $L$. Fortunately, $L$ embeds into the ring of Laurent series in the
variables $s_{1}/s_{2},\ s_{2}/s_{3},\ \ldots,\ s_{n-1}/s_{n},\ s_{n}$ (see
Section 2.2 of my paper for a formal definition of this ring; for the
analytically minded among us, this corresponds to the "regime" $\left| 
s_{1}\right| \ll\left|  s_{2}\right| \ll\cdots\ll\left| 
s_{n}\right| \ll1$); the fraction $\dfrac{s_{i}s_{j}+\beta s_{j}+\alpha
}{s_{i}-s_{j}}$ needs to be interpreted as $\dfrac{s_{i}+\beta+\alpha/s_{j}
}{s_{i}/s_{j}-1}$ in this case. Working in this latter ring allows one to
compare coefficients, which ideally should help proving linear independence.
However, I have not been successful with this approach.